# Consulta MySQL recursiva hacia padres y hermanos

Tags: mysql, recursión

> La idea es lanzar una única query la cual cuando se inserte o modifique una tarea, sea la tarea padre (que su **parent_task_id** apunta a null) o una tarea hija (que su **parent_task_id** apunta al id de su tarea padre) actualiza el campo horas de la tarea modificada y sume hasta llegar al proyecto, incluyendo los hermanos de las tareas padres, además, evitando la colisión de otra misma query, esto último con una transacción no sé si funcionaría correctamente en este caso.

#### Tengo las siguientes tablas:

---

**PROJECTS** *(resumen)*

- **id** integer auto_increment primary key
- **name** varchar(250) not null
- **hours** float not null default 0

**TASKS** *(resumen)*

- **id** integer auto_increment primary key
- **parent_task_id** integer null
- **project_id** integer not null
- **name** varchar(250) not null
- **description** text null
- **hours** float not null default 0

---

Por más vueltas que le he dado acabo en PHP rescatando el id de la tarea padre y sumando en bucle, lo cuál no lo veo correcto atacar tanto a la base de datos con algo tan habitual, ya que es posible que se lance la misma query en un intervalo de tiempo reducido.

Comment: Cuando yo tuve algo similar, en lugar de armar un query recursivo lo que hice fue traer de la bd toda la info que necesitaba y armar la estructura de árbol en la aplicación. Era similar a esos ejercicios de "convertir un arreglo en árbol".

Comment: Mm, es buena idea, crees que evita la colisión aunque haya transacción de por medio?

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es ir actualizando y un punto de sincronización, lo mejor sería por triggers en la base de datos.

Comment: He intentado lo de los trigger y encontré que no me permite actualizar dentro del trigger de inserción me arroja un código de error 1442.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un procedimiento recursivo en SQL se puede conseguir actualizar el número de horas en todas las TASKS y en el PROJECT:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_AddTaskTime`(
IN `para_task_id` INT,
IN `para_hours` FLOAT)

LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

-- Update task actual con las nuevas horas
UPDATE TASKS SET hours = hours + para_hours WHERE id = para_task_id;

-- Preparar la siguiente iteracion de recursividad
SET @PARENT_TASK_ID = (SELECT t.parent_task_id FROM TASKS t WHERE t.id = para_task_id);
SET @PROJECT_TASK_ID = (SELECT t.project_id FROM TASKS t WHERE t.id = para_task_id);

-- No hay parent_task: actualizar horas de proyecto y acabar
IF (@PARENT_TASK_ID IS NULL) THEN
    -- Update project
    UPDATE PROJECTS SET hours = (SELECT SUM(t.hours) FROM TASKS t 
                         WHERE t.project_id = @PROJECT_TASK_ID 
                         AND t.parent_task_id IS NULL) 
    WHERE id = @PROJECT_TASK_ID;
-- Existe un parent_task: continuar recursion con el parent
ELSE
    -- Llamada recursiva
    CALL SP_AddTaskTime(@PARENT_TASK_ID, para_hours);
END IF;

END
```

La función tiene 2 argumentos:

- `para_task_id` INT - Id del task actual. En cada llamada de la
  recursión, este parámetor irá cambiando de valor.
- `para_hours` FLOAT -Número de horas a añadir. Este parámetro permanece constante.

Lo primero que hace la función es añadir las horas al task id actual.

En el siguiente paso se lee el valor de la tarea padre y del projecto:

- Si la tare padre es `NULL`, no hay más tareas que añadir las horas, con lo que he llegado al final de la recursión y sólo queda actualizar el las horas del project.
- Si la tarea padre no es `NULL`, sigo la recursión con la task id de mi padre.

Un ejemplo de llamada al procedimiento sería:

```
CALL SP_AddTaskTime(3, 0.5);
```

Está llamada añadiría 0.5 horas a la `TASKS` con id = 3 y actualizaría todas las tareas padres y el número de horas totales del `PROJECTS`.

Por cierto, seguramente tendrás que cambiar el valor de la variable SQL `max_sp_recursion_depth`. Está variable indica el número de llamadas recursivas que se permiten. Si tienes una profundidad máxima de 10 tareas, este valor debes actualizarlo también:

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 10
```